# Tor-browser-launcher not working and giving ubuntu error popups

Tags: 22.04, tor

On Ubuntu 22.04 launching the tor browser launcher from the packages gives you a download error: 404.
This can be fixed by supplying
`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/common.py` with a `self.language = 'ALL'`. And now it will download the package.

The next error will be:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 442, in success
> self.run_task()
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 301, in run_task
> self.run()
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 477, in run
> if not self.check_min_version():
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 465, in check_min_version
> for line in open(self.common.paths["tbb"]["changelog"], "rb").readlines():
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_ALL/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/ChangeLog.txt'

So we create that file and location, running it throws yet another issue:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 442, in success
> self.run_task()
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 301, in run_task
> self.run()
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 477, in run
> if not self.check_min_version():
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 470, in check_min_version
> if version.parse(self.min_version) <= version.parse(installed_version):
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/packaging/version.py", line 49, in parse
> return Version(version)
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/packaging/version.py", line 264, in **init**
> match = self._regex.search(version)
> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

And this is where I got stuck. Does anyone have a fix for this? This issue has been present on 22.04 since the beginning.

Comment: This is a known bug, there has not been a published fix yet to the Ubuntu Repositories

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/torbrowser-launcher/+bug/2000077

Comment: That long has been long open....  ty